# Hession of linear network and its eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, neural-networks, hessian-matrix

I encounter this problem in my research. Assume we have $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}, U\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times h}, V\in\mathbb{R}^{h\times d}$. We consider the following function

$L(U,V)=\frac{1}{2}\lVert X-UV\rVert_F^2$.

My question is, for arbitrary $U, V$, what's the Hessian matrix of $L(U,V)$ and can we get an explicit formula for the eigenvalue depending on $U, V$? I can handle the vector case where $X \in \mathbb{R}, U\in \mathbb{R}^{1\times h}, V\in\mathbb{R}^{h\times 1}$, but when it comes to matrix case, I'm lost.

Comment: in which point you compute the Hessian?

Comment: for arbitrary $U, V$

Comment: then you want the eigenvalues relative to $U,V$?

Comment: yes. I modify the question to make it more clear. Thank you for clarification